# How can I find out the cell adress of the vlookup result

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a formula, that gives me back the cell address of a `vlookup` based on a date and a related 2-dim (array) `'Table!$A$4:$M$65'` of month/year.

```
4/30/1990  VLOOKUP(YEAR(L12),Table!$A$4:$M$65,MONTH(L12)+1))
```

The lookup works fine and  give me back the value of the looked up cell, but I additionally want the cell adress like **E32**.

Any idea how to ?

thanks in advance, Mole65

Comment: Just for more context, why do you need the cell address? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I want to quick find the cell adress in the table and later mark it with color

Comment: If you want to "later mark it with color", you could bypass the whole getting the address part and use conditional formatting instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of `ADDRESS` and `MATCH` should help:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(YEAR(L12),Table!$A$1:$A$26,0),MATCH(MONTH(L12),Table!$A$1:$M$1,0))
```

[image]

Table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always suggest using `INDEX`/`MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP`.

`INDEX`/`MATCH` can do everything `VLOOKUP` (and `HLOOKUP`) can do but it is:

- faster (important when used in many cells);
- more versatile (the value you are looking up does not need to be in a column to the right);
- more robust (inserting columns does not break it);
- easier to use (no column counting required);

If you used an `INDEX`/`MATCH` formula, such as this:

```
=INDEX(Table!$B$4:$M$65,MATCH(YEAR(L12),Table!$A$4:$A$65,0),MATCH(MONTH(L12),Table!$B$3:$M$3,0))
```

You could put it straight into a `CELL` function to return the full address:

```
=CELL(
    "address",
    INDEX(Table!$B$4:$M$65,MATCH(YEAR(L12),Table!$A$4:$A$65,0),MATCH(MONTH(L12),Table!$B$3:$M$3,0))
)
```

Example Table:
[image]

Example Result:
[image]

**AUTOMATICALLY COLOUR THE VALUE IN THE TABLE**

You do not need the address to highlight the value in the table.
Just create a conditional formatting rule for `$B$4:$M$65`:

```
=AND(MONTH(Sheet2!$L$12)=B$3,YEAR(Sheet2!$L$12)=$A4)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, many thanks ... one final question, how to use the cell command and get the return value w/o full path, just "E6" from your example?

Comment: The easiest way (although not most efficient) would be to simply wrap the `INDEX` formula into `ROW` and `COLUMN` functions, and put them inside an `ADDRESS` function: `=ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(Table!$B$4:$M$65,MATCH(YEAR(L12),Table!$A$4:$A$65,0),MATCH(MONTH(L12),Table!$B$3:$M$3,0))),COLUMN(INDEX(Table!$B$4:$M$65,MATCH(YEAR(L12),Table!$A$4:$A$65,0),MATCH(MONTH(L12),Table!$B$3:$M$3,0))),4,1)`